# simulate row_number with variables ignore order

Tags: mysql, sql, user-variables

I was trying to help with this question [Selecting rows based on a few rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57315945/selecting-rows-based-on-a-few-rules#57315945)

The idea is for each user select the row id with the language matching @lenguage otherwise select the first language created.

Because doesn't have `row_number()`, had to use user variables. Consider I add a field `test_id` so could put all the cases on the same table.

**[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/66b102/24)**

```
  SELECT t.* , (`language` = @language) as tt,
         @rn := if (@partition = CONCAT(`test_id`, '-', `user`),
                    @rn + 1,
                    if(@partition := CONCAT(`test_id`, '-', `user`), 1, 1)
                   ) as rn,
         @partition           
  FROM Table1 t
  CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @language := 'de', @rn := 0, @partition := '' ) as var
  ORDER BY CONCAT(`test_id`, '-', `user`), 
           (`language` = @language) DESC,
           `created`
```

**OUTPUT**

But even when the `ORDER BY` give the correct sort, partitions `1-4` and `3-4` don't put the language `'de'` as first. So something is altering how the variable `@rn` is being assigned.

```
| test_id | id | title | language |              created | user | tt | rn | @partition |
|---------|----|-------|----------|----------------------|------|----|----|------------|
|       1 |  3 |     c |       de | 2019-01-03T00:00:00Z |    4 |  1 |  3*|        1-4 |
|       1 |  1 |     a |       en | 2019-01-01T00:00:00Z |    4 |  0 |  1 |        1-4 |
|       1 |  2 |     b |       es | 2019-01-02T00:00:00Z |    4 |  0 |  2 |        1-4 |
|       2 |  1 |     a |       en | 2019-01-01T00:00:00Z |    4 |  0 |  1 |        2-4 |
|       2 |  2 |     b |       es | 2019-01-02T00:00:00Z |    4 |  0 |  2 |        2-4 |
|       3 |  1 |     a |       en | 2019-01-01T00:00:00Z |    3 |  0 |  1 |        3-3 |
|       3 |  3 |     b |       de | 2019-01-03T00:00:00Z |    4 |  1 |  2*|        3-4 |
|       3 |  2 |     b |       es | 2019-01-02T00:00:00Z |    4 |  0 |  1 |        3-4 |
|       3 |  4 |     c |       de | 2019-01-04T00:00:00Z |    5 |  1 |  1 |        3-5 |
```

Comment: MySQL manual says something about *"The order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is undefined."* pretty sure that happens here .. @Barmar 's suggestion seams to be correct..

Comment: @Barmar I add tt for debug, i had `(language = @language) DESC`in the `order by`. Unless you mean I have to create a subquery first to order before doing the @rn?

Comment: Whats is the complete output which you expected,  you should something about expecting the `de` first in a group?

Comment: Yes @RaymondNijland that is why I use `if()` to make sure the correct order is applied. The variables only change inside the `if()`

Comment: @RaymondNijland for partition `1-4` I expect 'de' be  1 and then 2,3. The order is correct but the variable should be `1,2,3` not `3,1,2`

Comment: you know how it works, ideally we would love to see a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. ?

Comment: What part  of MVC you think is missing @RaymondNijland ?

Comment: *"What part of MVC you think is missing"* Your comment only explains results for the `test_id = 1` based on the `OUTPUT`  but not for the `test_id = 2 / 3` cases? You didn't confirm those ordering where correct or incorrect.. Unless iam missing something obvious here as it is late over here..

Comment: The other cases are correct because doesn't have 'de' , only the rows I mark with * in the ouput has error.

Comment: Yes i see, problem is that simulating MySQL 8 syntax `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY .. ORDER BY ...)` is hard/tricky to simulate with MySQL user variables which i assume you are trying to do here?

Comment: Yes, but the thing Is I have done this many times before. This behavior is freaking me out.

Comment: Why you make language null? you need a value to make it first

Comment: I want it to be first. The order is ok. The problem is @rn isnt 1

Comment: *"Why you make language null? "* Your main problem is that `SELECT @language := 'de'`  because of the `(language= @language) DESC` part `de` is always sorted first..   if you check with `SELECT @language := 'es'`   `es` is sorted first..

Comment: Yes, I want select the id matching language first if exists, otherwise select the older one, that is why there are 2 order condition at the end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ordering is done after all the rows are selected. Your `@rn` variable is being set during the row selection, so it's using the internal order of rows, not the order specified in your `ORDER BY` clause.

You need to move the ordering into a subquery, then calculate `@rn` in the main query.

```
  SELECT t.*,
         @rn := if (@partition = CONCAT(`test_id`, '-', `user`),
                    @rn + 1,
                    if(@partition := CONCAT(`test_id`, '-', `user`), 1, 1)
                   ) as rn,
         @partition           
  FROM (
    SELECT *, (language = @language) AS tt
    FROM Table
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @language := 'de') AS var
    ORDER BY CONCAT(test_id, '-', user),
            tt DESC,
            created
  ) AS t
  CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @rn := 0, @partition := '' ) as var
```

Comment: I see that work, but why here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/69d52b/10 doesnt need a subquery?

Comment: When you're ordering on a table column directly, MySQL performs an optimization and does the ordering during extraction. But the query in the question, you're ordering by a computed value, so it can't extract from the table in that order.